# Firebase projected hosted on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, amazon-ec2, flutter-web

I am trying to build a multi-site platform using flutter and firebase. We are launching the web app version soon. I wanted to see if it is possible to host the web app using AWS instead of firebase hosting? And if so how do you do it?

Answer (score 1):

Technicaly that is possible. The hosting service from Firebase is enabling you "just" to host your website. If you want you can host it whereever you want (own server or even aws). I don't see any reason why it should not work if you just want to host the side.

Answer (score 1):

I hosted an Angular app using Firebase like backend as a service on AWS, so **it's possible**. In my case, I used Amazon S3 to upload the binaries generated by my Angular app. To deploy a Flutter App, I suggest you follow this article: [Build and deploy a Flutter Web app with Amazon S3 and Bitrise](https://blog.bitrise.io/post/build-and-deploy-a-flutter-web-app-with-amazon-s3-and-bitrise)